# using jQuery to start video element breaks normal controls

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a html5 `video` element with `poster` attribute on my site. I have a jQuery function that does the following.

```
$('video').click(function(){
    $(this).get(0).play();
});
```

This works fine: if I click the poster the video starts playing. However if I click the play button in the controls of the embedded video the poster goes a way but the video does not start to play. If I comment out the jQuery click-poster-to-start function the controls work.

How do I get both to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it ocures, but maybe this is an alternative option for you.

place a div under the video tag:

```
<video id="video" controls="controls">
 <source src="../video/IMG_0699.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="../video/IMG_0699.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm" />
 <source src="../video/IMG_0699.oggtheora.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<div id="poster"></div>
```

set positions to absolute:

```
#poster
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 213px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#video
{
    position: absolute;
width: 320px;
height: 251px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

and add the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
controlVideo();
function controlVideo(){
    $('#poster').click(function() {
        $('#video').get(0).play();
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#video').get(0).pause();
            controlVideo();
        });
    });
}   
});
```

I hope it helped you. It works fine for me. Ofcourse you have to set the height, widths and positions according to your page.